# How do I stop a number from being lower in an if statement

Tags: java, android, if-statement

In my app I have a reward system. It uses Firebase database to release the rewards.

For example if a user downloads 2 items and watches a short advert it registers their userid and the number 1 to the database. My app then receives that number and adds the relevant reward. But let's say I add the number 2 manually to my database for a prize for a competition or something similar, it does add the reward. But then if they download another item it cancels the reward and goes back to the number set by the official counting method I have set up.

Is there a way to say if the number is higher than the one in the official counting method do nothing?

This is my simple code:

```
 }else
    if (counter == 1) {
        mRewards.mstreaming.setBackground( mcontext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.buttonbkground2) );
```

If it already = 2 I don't want it to go back to the above.

Comment: if (counter >= 1) {} or maybe have 2 if's if (counter > 1) {} else if (counter == 1) {}... trying to figure out what you mean

Comment: does >=1 mean more than = 1? i think that may work.

Comment: >= means "greater than or equal to" ... @markharrop Maybe you should look over common syntax in the Java language to get a better idea of all the cool things you can do!

Comment: thanks #Zelda im going to have a look now

Comment: @markharrop You should definitely [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Comment: brilliant just what i was after thank you

Answer (score 1):

To do nothing you can just use return.

```
if(/*number>your counting method*/)return;
```

Comment: im just trying this now